# Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message."

Tags: python, json, api, youtube-api

So I've been trying to generate YouTube playlists with the corresponding video IDs, but when I try to do it in batches of 50, I get this error: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message." Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message.', 'reason': 'invalid'}]"

```
def add_songs_to_playlist(playlist_id, video_ids):
    for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 50):
        chunk = video_ids[i:i+50]
        video_objs = []
        for video_id in chunk:
            video_objs.append({
                "snippet": {
                    "playlistId": playlist_id,
                    "resourceId": {
                        "kind": "youtube#video",
                        "videoId": video_id
                    }
                }
            })
        try:
            youtube.playlistItems().insert(
                part="snippet",
                body=json.dumps(video_objs)
            ).execute()
        except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
            error_json = json.loads(e.content)
            if error_json["error"]["errors"][0]["reason"] == "videoNotFound":
                print(f"Video with ID {video_id} not found.")
            else:
                print(f"Error adding videos to playlist: {e}")
```

If I do separate API calls for each insert, it works, but that's not ideal because it uses up all my quotas. I made sure all the video IDs were valid. I also used jsonlint to make sure the JSON payload was valid, and it was valid. I have been trying everything so if anyone can help, please let me know.

Comment: Batching does not effect quota usage. If you batch 50 its still going to cost you Video insert quota * 50.  All batching saves you is the http request.

Comment: You say you validated the JSON payload as valid JSON, but is it in the format the YouTube API expects it? From the error message, it looks like it does not conform to what they expect to receive.

Comment: Okay and do you know if there is any work around to use less quotas when doing video insert?